# Are there a standard set of symbols for representing different classes of functions in documentation?

Tags: javascript, testing, documentation, notation

When describing a function in relation to its class (and I'm thinking in JavaScript although I reckon this could apply to most languages), I'm wondering if there are a standard set of symbols to denote the relationship of function to class.

For example it would make sense to me that a static or class function would be represented as

`ClassName.functionName`

since that's the way you would refer to it in code.

Other types of function would be instance methods and private function. Maybe there are more that I'm not considering (anonymous functions?).

When referring to these types of function in text (say, documentation or a test description) how do you represent the relationship between function and class? Currently I have different symbols that I use instead of the '.' but I'm wondering if there are standard symbols for this purpose.

Comment: http://usejsdoc.org/ might be of use

Comment: Thanks Daniel... although I'm quite familiar with that site but I'm not sure if there's anything about this on there. Have you seen a specific page that could be helpful?